# Akka actor invoked with a function delegate - is this bad practice?

Tags: scala, delegates, akka, actor

I'm building an actor system where a controller actor receives requests and spins up worker actors to perform the various tasks. The worker is invoked with a function delegate that specifies the actual task. So the worker is:

`class WorkerActor(workFunc: (OwlChunk=>Unit) => Unit) extends Actor`

And the controller spins it up with:

`actorRefFactory.actorOf(Props(classOf[WorkerActor], workFuncToBePerformed)`

where `OwlChunk=>Unit` represents a callback for progress reporting to the worker actor. 
I have all this running, and it works very well in my small testing environment, but I have a feeling I might be violating best-practices for actors. Am I? (For example, when the worker runs its workFunc, is it using bytecode that "belongs to" the controller actor? Is this bad in a distributed system?)

Comment: You are passing an immutable object of the type `Function`. This is perfectly fine.

Comment: Good to know. This seems like a useful pattern, but since I haven't come across it in any examples I was worried it might violate something.

Comment: I also use this pattern for a Play plugin that creates an actor (since it can't be an actor itself) and passes a function object to that actor.  Scala functions are very powerful.